# Master page functionality does not work on all content pages (asp.net webform)

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, content-pages

My master page has a few buttons to let the user choose his preferred culture.

```
protected void btnES_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Global.UserSession.Culture = "es-es";
    Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
}
```

On a new page that I have just added, that displays a Google map, this code does not run. My breakpoints are not hit. However it does work for the rest of the site. Is there some link between the content and master pages that I am missing?

This is from my map page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="MainMenu.master" CodeBehind="map.aspx.cs" Inherits="Choice.RI.UI.Map" %>
```

and this is from the master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MainMenu.master.cs" Inherits="Choice.RI.UI.MainMenu" %>
```

--- edit ---

there are no controls added programatically on the map page. all that I do on page load is to create a c# string object that contains the javascript to display the map and then I register it like this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "mapInit", script, true);
```

and my last line of code which interferes with the master is this, which simply removes some css to make the map appear fuller on the browser

```
(Master as MainMenu).RemoveStylingForMapPage();
```

and something else, I don't know whether this matters, the map page contains no form element.

Comment: Are you by any chance adding controls dynamically (from code-behind) into your content page ? If so can you share the  code how you're adding them.

Comment: no Ondrej, no dynamic controls. I edited my answer.

Comment: Ondrej, it was actually my own fault. I did not know that the page load of the content page runs before the master's. And I do have some validating code on the top of the content's page load that was doing a redirect to another page.

Sorry to waste your time.